# C# compare string that have Hierarchy CRM Dynamics

Tags: c#

The title might not be correct or misleading but here is my requirement, i need to compare strings in the following manner:
If we have two entities A and B one of the properties of these entities is a string named Region now in entity B i need to be able to associate entity A if the Region matches or has a higher level than the Region of B.

In other words if B has a Region named France.Bordeaux and A has a Region France i should still be able to associate them as Region France.Bordeaux is part of France.

Simply comparing the strings creates problems as France and France.Bordeaux are not same.

P.S all the Regions use the delimiter "." for example France.Bordeaux, France.SomeOtherSubRegion...

Code i have so far:

```
bool exist = false;
                foreach (var pc in A_Regions.Entities)
                {
                    foreach (var v in B_Regions.Entities)
                    {
                        if (v.GetAttributeValue<string>(Region.Name).Contains(pc.GetAttributeValue<string>(Region.Name)))
                        {
                            exist = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!exist)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("The vendor " + vendor.GetAttributeValue<string>(Vendor.Name) + " doesn't have a wine region that is a subgroup of the wine regions in this product call.");
                }
```

Im kinda new to c# programing and any pointers are welcomed

Comment: Did you try to solve the problem yourself? I'll have more success if you show some code. Maybe `String.indexOf` method can help you?

Comment: Can you just use the string StartsWith method?

Comment: show us what you have tried, we are not here to do your homework

Comment: @Agent_Orange https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: Agent_Orange i will not be able to copy and paste the code in anyway simply looking for a pointer. But sure i will paste the code so you can get an idea of what im doing.

Comment: @Mahdi I've seen the same message in "less nice" words ... _much less_

Comment: To elaborate Rob's suggestion: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jxnWZN

Comment: @Fildor: Just because there are less nice ways of phrasing it does not make it nice and polite (and certainly not useful or constructive).

Comment: @Chris I really don't want to go into an argument here, but "SO is not a codewriting service" is commonly accepted way of telling people that "SO is not a codewriting service". This is the first out of at least 1000 instances (that I am a whitness of) where somebody comes up with "be nice" to object that.

Comment: @Fildor: I have no problem with people saying that. Its Agent Orange's second comment that I consider rude and non-constructive (and I have assumed is the one Mahdi was commenting on too).

Comment: Guys i'm sorry if i offended anyone with my question, it is not for lack of trying, and even the answers that people give here will not be simply copied over, the problem that i have is much larger and the strings are nested 3-4 levels down, i simply have a deadline and i'm trying to get the task finished as fast as possible, please do not argue on behalf of my question and lack of knowledge on how to achieve this.

Comment: @Chris Well, yes. Ok. I guess it could be a question of how sensitive a person is. But I'll admit, that I personally would have found different wording (i.e. less accusatory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to split the strings and then compare them. Something like this, I am just comparing the first level because from what I understood I think this is enough?

```
var regionsA = entityA.Split('.');
var regionsB = entityB.Split('.');
```

This will give you an array of strings which are separated by '.' and you can compare them as needed.

Comment: huh man ! Dont answer question like this, he may copy paste your code :v

Comment: I haven't given him the answer because I didn't completely understand what he wants to achieve here; I have just provided a way he can achieve it, he will have to modify it to suit his needs. The whole purpose of this site is to help people and as you can read, he is new to C#.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar StackOverflow is not a code writing service! We don't write homeworks like you just did

Comment: The core of your answer is the Split() method, but you have it hidden inside hte block of code (with the pointless ToList call and redundant parentheses) which make it hard to find. You should make it the *focus* of the answer.

Comment: @VTodorov - Just providing a way to achieve it. I know this is not a code writing service, like I said; just helping.

Comment: Wow guys easy i just asked for an idea so i can get started, this is not homework copy paste moment, i have never had to compare strings in this way before so im just trying to get started from somewhere, this is part of a larger task, please chill and do not enter conflicts that are not nececary

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - Edited the answer, I hope it calms all of you down.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar thanks for the pointer much appreciated, sorry that you got grouped up for simply trying to help,cheers.

Comment: @FilipVancevski - no problem mate. Happy coding!

Comment: I'll had that you only have to compare the regionsA.Length-1 element of each array. Comparing all elements could be really time consuming if you have a lot of them.

Comment: Filip Vancevski and Raviraj Palvankar, hmm i m sorry for bad behavior, but as you guys know stackoverflow is a site that aims to teach people not a code writing service, and its difficult to know whose intention is to learn and whose to just copy paste, anyways a little tip for OP, you could also make a custom class for handling of hierarchy and childs, and add functions that compare them from inside!!